# HTML Email Template not showing background image in Outlook 365 anymore

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an HTML template that has a repeated background image and the image is hosted on https://imgbb.com/ (here is the image: https://i.ibb.co/NKYLjxT/topography-compressed.png).

Here is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='en-GB'>
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/> 
  <title>NaviGATE
  </title> 
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; padding: 50px 0 50px 0; background: url(https://i.ibb.co/NKYLjxT/topography-compressed.png); font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 1.6'> 
  <table role='presentation' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'> 
<tr> 
  <td> 
    <table align='center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' style='border-collapse: collapse;'> 
      <tr> 
        <td> 
          <table style='border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%'> 
            <tr> 
              <td align='center' bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 40px 0 30px 0;'> 
                <img src='###company logo###' alt='' width='300' style='display: block;'/> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
              <td bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;'> 
                <p style='margin: 0;'>BODY OF EMAIL
                  <br/>
                  <br/> 
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
              <td bgcolor='#2f3c48' style='padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;'> 
                <p style='margin: 0;'>
                  <a href='#homepage#' style='color: #ffffff'>internal home page
                  </a>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </td>
</tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When viewing the email in Outlook 365, the background image doesn't show up at first. **But when the window is resized, it shows up like normal**. Same behavior on another computer using Outlook 365. On Gmail everything appears as normal.

Is there something I can do differently in the HTML to force it to show up?

I've compressed the image as much as I could. I tried using a vector of the image to use it in inline CSS, but it didn't work (the code was massive). I tried encoding in Base64, no luck either.

I don't think it is an Outlook setting because about a month ago when I originally tested the template, it appeared as normal. Maybe the most recent patch broke it? I'm not sure. Using `Version 2104 (Build 13929.20296)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background property (only when there is a URL) is not supported in Outlook. The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The article you posted is for Outlook 2007 so doesn't apply to my specific issue. [Outlook 365 is able to support background images](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/css-background-images-now-supported-in-outlook-com/#:~:text=Outlook.com%20and%20Office%20365,now%20supports%20CSS%20background%20images.&text=This%20restriction%20forced%20email%20designers,background%20image%20in%20Outlook.com.).

Comment: Outlook.com and Outlook for Desktop are different things! The rules described in the article can be applied to all Outlook versions. Try using Word for displaying your markup.

Comment: Ok I see, I'm using Outlook 2014. I tried using Word to display my markup and it also doesn't work. But Outlook _does_ display the markup as expected when I resize the message window. Also, 2 weeks ago when I first tested it, it simply displayed as I expected it would. Not sure what changed, but I'll see if the article will help me and post what I find.

Comment: Update. Year later, I actually don’t think I got this to work for my employer at the time